# anchor tag href creation with backslash in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I want to pass `RXKJ/00000004/2013` with my url in codeigniter. I have done

```
'<a href="'.base_url().'policy/manage/policy/riskDetails/'.urlencode('RXKJ/00000004/2013').'">RXKJ/00000004/2013</a>'
```

but not working.

Comment: What do you mean by *not working*?

Comment: riskDetails is my controller function. after clicking the link it is giving The requested URL /~tristar/policy/manage/policy/riskDetails/RXKJ/00000004/2013 was not found on this server.

Comment: use base64_encode........

Comment: rtrim(base64_encode($variable]),'=')...............try with this.......

Comment: @Venkat base64_encode this is working. for decoding what will i us?

Comment: base64_decode($variable)

Comment: @Venkat thanks. It's perfectly working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encode any variable using base64_encode and decode using base64_decode.........

```
$encoded = base64_encode($variable]);

$decoded = base64_decode($encoded);
```

You can find more about [Base64_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php)